# Convertir Array a XML

Tags: php, xml

Hola buenas tardes tengo un Array con solo un registro hasta el momento, pero lo que necesito es convertir ese array en formato XML y de una forma dinámica para cuando existan mas de un registro en el Array.

> Array con registros

```
$array_llamadas = array(
                    'id_CLIENTE'=>$id_CLIENTE, 
                    'RAZON_SOCIAL'=>"nombre_cuenta", 
                    'ORIGEN'=>$ORIGEN, 
                    'TIPO_TEL_DESTINO'=>$TIPO_TEL_DESTINO, 
                    'DESTINO'=>$DESTINO, 
                    'TIPO_TRAFICO'=>$TIPO_TRAFICO, 
                    'POBLACION_DESTINO'=>$POBLACION_DESTINO, 
                    'DURACION_MIN'=>$duracion_minutos, 
                    'FECHA'=>$fecha_inicio1, 
                    'TARIFA_BASE'=>$TARIFA_BASE, 
                    'MONTO_FINAL'=>$MONTO_FINAL
                );

                print_r($array_llamadas);
```

> Array impreso en pantalla

```
Array ( [id_CLIENTE] => 2823 [RAZON_SOCIAL] => nombre_cuenta [ORIGEN] => 4427073049 [TIPO_TEL_DESTINO] => ONNET_IN [DESTINO] => 1474421667101 [TIPO_TRAFICO] => ONNET_IN [POBLACION_DESTINO] => GUANAJUATO/QUERETARO [DURACION_MIN] => 0 [FECHA] => 02-02-2020 [TARIFA_BASE] => 0 [MONTO_FINAL] => 0 )
```

> Formato de XML que necesito el Array

```
<ZohoCreator>
    <applicationlist>
        <application name='zoho-cdr'>
            <formlist>
                <form name='Detalle_de_Llamada1'>
                    <add>
                        <field name='RAZON_SOCIAL'>
                            <value>Javierkawaii</value>
                        </field>
                        <field name='ORIGEN'>
                            <value>Prueba</value>
                        </field>
                    </add>
                    <add>
                        <field name='RAZON_SOCIAL'>
                            <value>Jean</value>
                        </field>
                        <field name='ORIGEN'>
                            <value>Prueba uno</value>
                        </field>
                    </add>
                </form>
            </formlist>
        </application>
    </applicationlist>
</ZohoCreator>
```

Intente con la siguiente instrucción, pero no me esta quedando

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($test_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
print $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: Esa instrucción que intentas a duras penas logra usar los valores como etiqueta y los keys del array como valor interno. El XML de destino requiere harto más trabajo para dejarlo igual...

Comment: de echo solo necesito poder convertir el array a XML, de ordenar los datos y demás yo me encargo solo que no logro convertir mi Array a XML